# Hamburger navbar not displaying using CSS .active

Tags: html, css, validation, nav, hamburger-menu

I'm really scratching my head at this one. I've been following a tutorial on Youtube line for line to make a Hamburger menu to make my site more mobile friendly. I've followed it but when I get to the part when using the .hamburger {display: block;} it doesn't appear. My entire nav-bar vanishes too.

The video does not include a source code, and nobody in the comments seems to have the same issue. I've spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out why it's not showing up. Gone back and edited my code over again, checked for typo's tried online CSS validators... but I've gotten no where. JavaScript will be added later into the code so there are some things that may not work until then, but mine wont even show up at all beforehand. I'm using Codepen for convenience but would that cause issue?

Do you happen to see or know why my hamburger does not display when activated?

```css
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
header{
  background-color: black;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar {
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 24px;
  gap: 60px;
}
.nav-branding {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.nav-link {
  transition: 0.7s ease;
}
.nav-link:hover{
  color:dodgerblue;
}
.hamburger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: white;
}
@media(max-width:768px) {
  .hamburger{
    display: block
  }
  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2){
    opacity:0;
  }
  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1){
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3){
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}
}
  .nav-menu{
    position: fixed;
    left: -100%;
    top: 70px;
    gap: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
    
  }
  .nav-item {
    margin: 16px 0;
  }
  
  .nav-menu.active{
    left: 0;
  }
```

```html
<body>
<header>
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="nav-branding">Dev.</a>
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
      </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
<div class="hamburger">
         <span class="bar"></span>
         <span class="bar"></span>
         <span class="bar"></span>
         </div>
    </header>
  </body>
```

Comment: You gave the value of `left:-100%;` to the `.nav-menu` class. Could it be related to that?

Comment: Hmm I removed it entirely, and also changed it to just 100% (no negative) and it didn't appear. :(

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues here. Take a look at the CSS in my answer, I scoped a lot of the styling to the media query so that it didn't affect your navigation when on bigger screens. You were also using `position: fixed` for `.nav-menu`, better would be to use `position: absolute` and add `position: relative` to the `.navbar`

The `.nav-menu` is set to be off the screen using `transform: translateX(-100vw)` because transforms are much more predicable to use because `top/right/bottom/left positioning` can sometimes resize elements depending how they're laid out. Transforms are also much easier for browsers to calculate

I also setup a very basic bit of JavaScript to toggle the active class, this add the class to `.navbar` instead of to `.hamburger` and `.nav-menu` and the CSS was the updated to account for this

Any questions let me know, happy to explain further

```js
const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', function (e) { navbar.classList.toggle('active') });
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } body { backgroud-colour: red; font: 16px sans-serif; margin: 0 }
a { color: white; text-decoration: none }
header { background-color: black }


:root {
  --transitionDelay: 0ms;
  --transitionSpeed: 500ms;
  --transitionFunction: cubic-bezier(0.860, 0.000, 0.070, 1.000);
  --transitionFunctionBar: cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550);


  --transition: var(--transitionSpeed) var(--transitionDelay) var(--transitionFunction);
  --transitionBar: var(--transitionSpeed) var(--transitionDelay) var(--transitionFunctionBar);
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  gap: 60px;
}
.nav-branding { font-size: 2rem }
.nav-link { transition: color var(--transition) }
.nav-link:hover{ color: dodgerblue }
.hamburger { display: none }

.nav-menu{
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  .navbar { position: relative }

  .hamburger{ cursor: pointer; display: block }
  
  .bar {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 3px; width: 25px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: opacity var(--transitionBar), transform var(--transitionBar);
  }
  
  .nav-menu {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, white 20%, black 80%);
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 400%;

    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scale(0) translate(100vw, -100%);
    transform-origin: calc(100% - 1.5rem) calc(1.5rem * -1.75);
    transition: background-position var(--transition), transform var(--transition);
  }
  
  .nav-item {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    transition: transform var(--transitionSpeed) var(--transitionDelay) var(--transitionFunction);
  }
  .nav-item:nth-of-type(1) { --transitionDelay: calc( var(--transitionSpeed) / 2 + ( 1 * 50ms ) ) }
  .nav-item:nth-of-type(2) { --transitionDelay: calc( var(--transitionSpeed) / 2 + ( 2 * 50ms ) ) }
  .nav-item:nth-of-type(3) { --transitionDelay: calc( var(--transitionSpeed) / 2 + ( 3 * 50ms ) ) }
  .nav-item:nth-of-type(4) { --transitionDelay: calc( var(--transitionSpeed) / 2 + ( 4 * 50ms ) ) }
  .nav-item:nth-of-type(5) { --transitionDelay: calc( var(--transitionSpeed) / 2 + ( 5 * 50ms ) ) }
  .nav-item:nth-of-type(6) { --transitionDelay: calc( var(--transitionSpeed) / 2 + ( 6 * 50ms ) ) }
  .nav-item:nth-of-type(7) { --transitionDelay: calc( var(--transitionSpeed) / 2 + ( 7 * 50ms ) ) }
  .nav-item:nth-of-type(8) { --transitionDelay: calc( var(--transitionSpeed) / 2 + ( 8 * 50ms ) ) }
  .nav-item:nth-of-type(9) { --transitionDelay: calc( var(--transitionSpeed) / 2 + ( 9 * 50ms ) ) }
  .nav-link {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: block;
    padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
    transition: background-color var(--transition), color var(--transition);
  }
  .nav-link:hover { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) }
  
  .navbar.active .bar:nth-child(2) { opacity: 0 }
  .navbar.active .bar:nth-child(1) { transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg) }
  .navbar.active .bar:nth-child(3) { transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg) }
  .navbar.active .nav-menu {
    background-position: bottom right;
    transform: scale(1) translate(0);
    transition: background-position calc(var(--transitionSpeed) * 2) 300ms var(--transitionFunction), transform var(--transition);
  }
  .navbar.active .nav-item { transform: translateX(0) }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="nav-branding">Dev.</a>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```